# Need some ideas on how one can spam some website, crawl some website and waste it's resources

Tags: web, spam, spam-prevention

I am working on a startup which basically serves website. Sorry, I can't reveal much details about the startup.

I need some ideas on how spammers and cralwer devs think on attacking some website. And if possible, then a way to prevent such attacks too.

We have come up with some basic ideas like:

```
1. Include a small JS file in the sites that would send an ACK on our servers ones all the assets are loaded. Like some crawlers/bots only come to websites and download specific stuff like images or articles. In such cases, our JS won't be triggered. And when we study our logs, which will have a record of resources requested by the particular IP and if out JS was triggered or not. We can then whitelist or blacklist IP's based on the study.

2. Like email services do, we will load a 1x1 px image on the client side via an API call. In simple words, we won't add the "img" tag directly in out HTML, but rather a JS that calls an API on our server that returns the image to the client. 

3. We also have a method to detect Good bots like that of google which indexes our pages. So we can differentiate between good bots and bad bots that just waste our resources.
```

We are at a very basic level. Infact, all our code does right now is logs the IP's and assets requested by that IP in elasticsearch. 
And so we need ideas on how people spam/crawl  websites via cralwers/bots/etc. So we can come up with some solution. And if possible, please also mention the pros and cons and ways to defend against your ideas too.

Thanks in advance. If you share your ideas, you'll be helping a startup which will be doing a lot of good stuff.

Comment: How will you handle visitors who have JavaScript disabled?

Comment: @HerbWolfe We are sill coming up with ideas regarding that. Maybe we'll make some modifications in step 2. Like we will add the "img" in our HTML. But "src" won't have a link to our image. It will have an API call insead. We are all beginners here in this startup. So we need ideas.